# How to read, store and delete xml data in C#

Tags: c#, xml, save

```
<SMSWall run="yes" nonstop="False">
    <starttime>10:15:25 PM</starttime>
    <endtime>10:15:25 PM</endtime>
</SMSWall>
<MediaPlayer run="yes" nonstop="False">
    <starttime>10:15:25 PM</starttime>
    <endtime>10:15:25 PM</endtime>
</MediaPlayer>
<Bidding run="yes" nonstop="False">
    <starttime>10:15:25 PM</starttime>
    <endtime>10:15:25 PM</endtime>
</Bidding>
```

This is my xml file. Now I want to read the xml, store the value in a variable (and also want the data to read from the string), and leave the .xml file so that it can be deleted.I also want to read the value node wise like:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("Schedule.xml");
XmlNode ht=document.SelectSingleNode("SMSWall/@run");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current XML file is not in correct format (i.e save it as .xml and open it with IE, you will give an error). So you should add `<root> ... </root>` (or other name).
In all I think best way to treat with XML is using System.Xml.Linq library, like [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) :

```
Loading data: XDocument.Load(filename);
Creating item: XElement root = new XElement("Root");
Searching: document.Descendants("Root"), ...
```

See MSDN for other samples.

Comment: okey tht's a part of my .xml file.I just want to know that I have read the values using that code.but if I store them in a Dataset how can i do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create a `DataSet` and then use it like this:

```
DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
ds.ReadXml("test.xml", XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
//do something
ds.WriteXml("test.xml", XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
```

A typed `DataSet` will provide you typed tables and rows. You can get rows by index or query. You can find more about the [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Articles/StronglyTypedDatasets.aspx).

Comment: okey that's fine.I have already saw such post.But the problem is how can I read the value from the data set,as I am reading from the .xml file.And also read a single node.

Comment: hey thnx for the help.what can I do after words,I mean how can I read the values.from the .xml file.